# Windows Command for mysqldump of all views in a database?

Tags: command-line, view, command, mysql

How can I take dump of all views in my mysql database. I don't need table structure, procedures..etc. Only views are required.

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: are you asking to dump the definitions of the views, or the data returned by running the view? Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh 
SRC_USER=root 
SRC_PASS=secret 
SRC_DB=mydb 
SRC_DB_HOST=10.10.10.1 
DEST_DB_HOST=localhost 
DEST_USER=$SRC_USER 
DEST_PASS=$SRC_PASS 
DEST_DB=$SRC_DB  

# External tools needed used by this script 
MYSQLDUMP=/usr/bin/mysqldump 
MYSQL=/usr/bin/mysql 
FGRES=/usr/bin/fgres  

# Dump database 
$MYSQLDUMP -u $SRC_USER -p$SRC_PASS --opt $DB -h $DB_HOST > $DB.sql  

# Replace the DEFINER lines with appropriate user@host 
$FGRES "$SRC_DB_HOST" "$DEST_DB_HOST" $DB.sql  

# Now insert the database in destination 
$MYSQL -u $DEST_USER -p$DEST_PASS -D $DEST_DB < $DB.SQL
```

you might check [this link](http://mysqlhacker.com/kabir/dba/exporting-dumping-views-using-mysqldump.html).